# VBA Code to hide and unhide empty rows on multiple sheets

Tags: vba

I am having problem to make this code work - any help is much appreciated! I know the issue is to do with the first line...I have a `Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)` above this code to address other elements that I need VBA code for.

```
Private Sub HideAndUnhideRowsInOtherWorksheet()
    For Each c In Worksheets("FlatStage").Range("A7:A32")
        If c.Value = "" Then
            c.EntireRow.Hidden = True
        Else
            c.EntireRow.Hidden = False
        End If
    Next
    For Each c In Worksheets("Efficiency").Range("A7:A32")
        If c.Value = "" Then
            c.EntireRow.Hidden = True
        Else
            c.EntireRow.Hidden = False
        End If
    Next
    For Each c In Worksheets("DayRate").Range("A7:A10,A14:A22,A25:A25,A28:A39")
        If c.Value = "" Then
            c.EntireRow.Hidden = True
        Else
            c.EntireRow.Hidden = False
        End If
    Next
    For Each c In Worksheets("AddServ").Range   ("A6:A8,A10:A11,A13:A17")
        If c.Value = "" Then
            c.EntireRow.Hidden = True
        Else
            c.EntireRow.Hidden = False
        End If
    Next
    For Each c In Worksheets("Enhancement").Range("A6:A7")
        If c.Value = "" Then
            c.EntireRow.Hidden = True
        Else
            c.EntireRow.Hidden = False
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: are we supposed to guess what the issue is?

Answer (score 0):

If you call the code from the above `Worksheet_Change()` it should work, but if you call your Sub from another module it will not be visible because it's declared as **`Private`** (to that particular module)

All you need to do is change `Private` to **`Public`**
(or move it to a new generic module and make it **`Public`** there)

---

On the other hand, the screen might flash while it is executing
To fix this turn off `ScreenUpdating` before the loops, and turn it back on after

But you can also reduce the code so it will be easier to maintain:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub HideAndUnhideRowsInOtherWorksheet()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    ToggleRows Worksheets("FlatStage").Range("A7:A32")
    ToggleRows Worksheets("Efficiency").Range("A7:A32")
    ToggleRows Worksheets("DayRate").Range("A7:A10,A14:A22,A25:A25,A28:A39")
    ToggleRows Worksheets("AddServ").Range("A6:A8,A10:A11,A13:A17")
    ToggleRows Worksheets("Enhancement").Range("A6:A7")

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Private Sub ToggleRows(ByRef colRng As Range)
    If Not colRng Is Nothing Then
        Dim c As Range
        For Each c In colRng
            c.EntireRow.Hidden = Len(c.Value2) = 0
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

---

Or, even smaller and faster if you can use `AutoFilter`:

```
Private Sub FilterRows(ByRef colRng As Range)
    If Not colRng Is Nothing Then
        colRng.Parent.UsedRange.Columns(colRng.Column).AutoFilter 'Filter symbol in top cell
        colRng.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<>"
    End If
End Sub
```

---

This sub will unhide all rows in all worksheets

```
Public Sub UnhideAllRowsInAllWorksheets()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In Worksheets
        With ws.UsedRange
            If ws.AutoFilterMode Then .AutoFilter   'ws.ShowAllData
            .Rows.EntireRow.Hidden = False
        End With
    Next
End Sub
```